# How do you backup your photos?

Tags: digital, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What method is best to take backups of your digital photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/292/what-method-is-best-to-take-backups-of-your-digital-photos)

Just as the question says: How do you guys back up your images?

- CDs
- DVDs
- SD cards
- Internal/external HDD or SSD
- USB flash drives
- Cloud
- Floppy discs
- Other?

I've got a ton of images and very little hard disc space, so I think I'm going to start backing up my images via DVD. I sorta wish I had enough money to buy a bunch of SD cards because I think that would be much nicer (and netbook friendly). I'd really like to hear what you do.

Go ahead, what's your backup solution?

Comment: This question has received a lot of answers already. I can try merging it with its duplicates, but it might be hairy business. Should we just keep this as-is, since it has become an active topic on its own?